# Why are electric power lines so highly visible in satellite images?

Tags: satellite, resolution

In Google Maps, why are electric power lines so highly visible? I can find them every place in the United States that has above-ground power.

For example, in the Google Maps image below, the high voltage lines are clearly visible. And, above the white boat and trailer near the center of the image, the residential (grid/mains) power lines are also visible.

[image]

In my area of the U.S., I estimate that high voltage lines are about 1.5" (4cm) in diameter, and residential power lines to houses are about 0.5" (1.25cm) in diameter.

The width of both lines is surely less than the resolution of the satellite images, so why are they still highly visible?

Edit: Good observation by user30184 that an object that is sufficiently long, sufficiently uniform in color, and with sufficient contrast to its background can be visible well below camera resolution.

The same picture above, but zoomed back so far that vehicles are ambiguous, the power lines are still visible in the right of way for the high voltage lines.

[image]

Comment: These aren't satellite images, but aerial images taken from airplanes. Also, I think you're underestimating the diameter of power lines. 1.5" is roughly the width of the line to a single residence.

Comment: also distribution corridors are kept free from growth of vegetation including large trees... drones and helicopters can be also used to capture lidar/imagery for routine maintenance.

Comment: @Tom In my area, residential power lines are very close to 0.5" in diameter -- I just need to look out the window.

Comment: Perhaps some are not visible, and go unnoticed.

Comment: You do not see the wires in the image. It is obvious at the lower left corner where wires are above the white truck. But the shiny wires are reflecting so much light that the average value of the whole pixel turns into light grey and you can see the row of light pixels above the dark ground and vegetation.

Comment: @user30184 Not sure what you're saying here -- everything that we see with our eyes is reflected light, unless we're observing a light emitter. So we're seeing the wires in the same way that we see the grass, the roof of the houses, etc.

Comment: I mean that you can distinguish objects, especially linear ones like power lines and ditches, which are much smaller/narrower than the pixel size if their contrast to the surroundings is high enough. 1.5 inch power line can paint the whole 15 inch pixel as rather light.

Comment: And furthermore I guess the ones in your pictrure are at least 3 times higher than the house is. Them being closer to the camera might play a role also.

Answer (score 0):

It might be dangerous to assume that if you don't see them on google maps, then there aren't any there.
Here's [one near me](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.6328111,-98.4444691,3a,60y,254.51h,92.66t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1skcVBSpexyB5qJ9BckOT_CQ!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en) that shows in google streetview:
[image]

But doesn't appear in [the satellite view](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.6327105,-98.4444784,145m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en):
[image]

Google has processed the area for 3D.  The [3D view](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.6336652,-98.4460923,125a,35y,124.24h,55.04t/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) shows bits and pieces:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what maps you are looking at, but the lines at Encio Cabin/Encio Rio are very visible: https://www.google.com/maps/@29.6327406,-98.4439313,160m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

Comment: It looks like the satellite image captured the distribution line, but not the transmission line next to it. https://www.google.com/maps/@29.6324962,-98.4445176,3a,60y,290.87h,96.88t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sXt5s30OjRP78R1VtiIGaLw!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en

Comment: Maybe the camera was focused more on things closer to the ground.